# Android streaming video to server

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm new to android, and having trouble finding information about how to send live video using camera2 to a server for image processing.

I've been searching google for a few hours, but all I can find is information about watching a live stream from an android device or basic information regarding camera2

Any suggestions about where to look or how to get started would be very much appreciated

Comment: search for android as ip camera ,video calling , webrtc , live streaming etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a picture every n seconds and then upload it using firebase. Not sure any other way.